# how to increase viewpager performance in android

Tags: android-activity, android-viewpager

I'm devoloping a simple android app that has two activity ( let's call activity1 and activity2 ).

Activity2 contain a viewpager that has 50 pages. Because i want to increase performance when switching page of viewpager so i set offscreenlimit up to 15 page ( because my app mostly use activity 2 ).

For that reason when i switch from activity1 to activity2 ( when start app i will begin with activity1 and then switch to activity2 ) i take quite a lot of time and make my app isn't smooth as i expected.

To solve this problem i has been thinking about preload activity2 when i'm working on activity1 but it's seem android doesn't support preload activity. Another solution i think about is preload viewpager. but i don't know how to send loaded viewpager between activity

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android ViewPager automatically caches limited number of pages and not load all of them at once. It will create required pages on demand. By default it caches 3 views (one you can see, and the left one and right one of current one). But for optimizing the performance, I suggest you to use things like using views with small sized bitmaps (if you have any). I mean do not use large images for background or if you can use single-color backgrounds instead of bitmap-backgrounds. This one will really improve performance of your viewpager.